# Access to specific property of a definition in Swagger

Tags: yaml, swagger

How can I access to an specific definition's property? I need in my 200's response to show an property in the "schema" node, not the whole "definition".

Here is the Yaml code:

```
paths: 
 /user/{user_id}:
            get:
              description: Devuelve un `user` pasándole su `user_id`.
              produces:
                - application/json
              parameters:
                - name: user_id
                  in: path
                  description: Identificador del `user`.
                  required: true
                  type: string
                  format: VarChar (255)
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: Ok 
                  schema:
                    $ref: "#/definitions/User"

definitions:
  User:
    properties:
      user_id:
        type: integer
        format: BigInt
        description: Identificador del usuario.
      email:
        type: string
        format: VarChar (255)
        description: Email del usuario
      pwd:
        type: string
        format: VarChar (255)
        description: Password del usuario.
```

I mean, I just need something like this:

```
responses:
                    '200':
                      description: Ok 
                      schema:
                        $ref: "#/definitions/User/user_id"
```

Any thought?

Answer (score 3):

The response needs to be a proper schema.  And your reference needs to follow the elements in the actual object.

If you do this:

```
'200':
  description: Ok 
  schema:
    $ref: "#/definitions/User/properties/user_id"
```

It should work fine.